# onchange event for an input[type="date"] not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, input, onchange

Im rather new to javascript and the MVC world so forgive the possibly easy problem.

I have a table of date type inputs where the user needs to select dates for each named row. To allow the user to visually see they have made a change I have created class called "visited" which creates a border around the cell. At the moment the input has an inline onchange event which adds this class when the user changes one of the dates. So far it all works perfectly.

However, for numerous reasons I need to listen for these onchange events to drive things like checking for dirty cells, so I have tried to move the inline code into a javascript function instead in my js file. Once im comfortable that its working I can add the dirty checks etc. However, no matter what I try I cannot get it to work in a function. I have read a few threads which explain that onchange events are tailored to text fields as they work on keyups etc. But I cannot find an alternative that works, be it oninput events, eventlistners, queryselectoralls etc. Please help this struggling novice!

Below is my HTML with the inline onchange function left in;

```
<td><input class="dateTest" type="date" onchange="this.className=(this.value=='')?'':'visited';"  onclick="this.showPicker()" prevvalue="@dateString" value="@dateString" min="@previousString" max="@endString" /></td>
```

my latest javascript attempt with added value check;

```
$(".dateTest").change(function (c) {
    var cell = $(this);
    cell.addClass("visited");
    console.log(cell.val());
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to use *both* the inline event handler *and* the jQuery event handler?  Are they both executing?  Can you update this to a runnable [mcve] which specifically demonstrates the problem?

Comment: What exact error(s) do you get? [The basics of your setup work](https://jsbin.com/jimudutuni/1/edit?html,js,console,output). You can attach an event listener. However, 1. you're missing a closing `)` in the JS 2. you have more inline JS. Any number of these things might fail and stop the entire thing from working. It's not clear if that's what you experience and even if it's something with the code presented here, what the actual problem is. [edit] to add a [mcve]

Comment: If you fix the missing `)` in the JS, then the code works: https://jsfiddle.net/oytn598w/. I also note that you're using a custom control - `this.showPicker` - check that this still allows you to use native events.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend NOT using inline events. Reasoning: inline events do NOT stack and will become overwritten. Other issues might include CSP (Content Security Policy) not working properly.

```js
// wait for html on page to load first before running JS
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // place all the inputs into an array
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".tbl_inputs");
    // cycle each input and add an event listener "change"
    inputs.forEach(($input) => {
       // on change triggers when the value of the element changes AND the element is blurred.
       $input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
          e.target.classList.add("visited");
       });
    });
});
```

```css
input.tbl_inputs.visited {
  background: #bbb;
}

.tbl_inputs {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="tbl_inputs" type="text" value="Hello World"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="tbl_inputs" type="text" value="Hello World"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```